# Wann ist es angebracht, „Mädels/Jungs“ anstelle „Frauen/Männer“ zu nutzen?

Tags: colloquial

Ich bevorzuge, *Frauen* bzw. *Männer* zu sagen. Aber ich merke, etliche Muttersprachler nennen Menschen *Mädels* und *Jungs* anstelle dessen, welches ich als *Frauen* und *Männer* bezeichnen würde.

- Wann ist es angebracht, *Mädels* bzw. *Jungs* zu nutzen? (Ich nutze das kaum, weil es mir ein bisschen kindlich vorkommt, welches nur ein Vorurteil ist).
- Wenn die Frage sich noch nicht konkret beantwortet ließe, in welchem Altersbereich des Sprechers und der Person, die genannt wird, sollte man diese Varianten nutzen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das hat schon in erster Linie etwas mit dem Alter zu tun.

Jungs = Plural von Junge = junger Mann /Kind (männlich)

Mädel = umgangssprachlich für Mädchen = junge Frau/ Kind (weiblich)

Daher kann man, wenn man von Kindern redet, immer "Jungs" bzw. "Mädels" benutzen.

Will man die Begriffe aber für erwachsene Leute verwenden, so sollte man einige Feinheiten beachten:
"Jungs" bzw. "Mädels" hat eine familiäre/vertraute Konnotation, daher ist die Verwendung nur dann unbedenklich, wenn es sich dabei wirklich um eine Gruppe befreundeter Personen handelt.

Der Chef eines Unternehmens, würde sich z.B. nie bei den "Jungs und Mädels die hier arbeiten", sondern immer bei den "Männern und Frauen" bedanken, wenn er seine Belegschaft loben will.

Gerade die Bezeichnung "Mädels" kann, im falschen Kontext, als Diminutiv und daher abwertend aufgefasst werden. Ich würde zur Vorsicht raten.

Daher mein Tipp: Verwendung ähnlich wie im Englischen "Buddys" oder "Pals" bei Jungs und "Girls" bei Mädels.

Comment: "Der Chef würde sich nie" ist ein frommer Wunsch. Solche Vertraulichkeiten und Infantilisierungen greifen mehr und mehr um sich, und gerade einen Chef traut sich kaum wer zu kritisieren.

Comment: Das Beispiel mit den "Mädels" und "Der Chef würde nie" habe ich bereits 1998 während eines Schülerpraktikums erlebt und damals als herablassend/frauenfeindlich interpretiert. Es war jedoch nicht so gemeint, teilte der Chef mir später mit. Welche Wirkung so eine Aussage hat, lässt sich in der Tat nur schwer von außen beurteilen.

Answer (score 4):

"Mädels" und "Jungs" werden häufig für Bekanntenkreise/Freundeskreise benutzt, der Gebrauch ist aber meines Wissens nicht darauf beschränkt.

So sind oft gebrauchte Aussagen z. B.

> "Ich gehe mit den Jungs einen trinken."

oder

> "Ich geh heute Abend mit meinen Mädels aus."

Der Gebrauch in dem Beispiel hier ist eher umgangssprachlich.

*Was man nicht bzw. selten sagen würde:*

"Ich gehe mit den Männern einen trinken."
"Das ist das Jungs-Klo"
"Das ist die Jungs-Umkleide"

*Das lässt folgenden Schluss zu:*

Fast nur wenn es um direkte Diversifizierung von Geschlechtern geht, dann benutzt man Männer/Frauen bzw. Herren/Damen.

"Jungs" bzw. "Mädels" enthält zwar ebenfalls die Aussage über das Geschlecht der Gruppe, wird aber eher für das einfache Benennen einer solche Gruppe genutzt.

Comment: +1 für Freundeskreise. Ich frage mich aber grade, ob meine Generation auch im Seniorenalter noch "mit den Jungs" einen trinken gehen wird. So richtig kann ich mir das grade nicht vorstellen.

Answer (score 3):

Mit dem Alter hat das nur am Rande zu tun. Kinder kann man als Mädchen und Jungs (oder Buben) bezeichnen, aber auch später kann man die Bezeichnung Mädels und Jungs (oder Burschen) durchaus verwenden. Die Ausdrucksweise ist salopp und umgangssprachlich aber weit verbreitet.

Die Verwendung ist ähnlich wie im Englischen:

> Ein Abend mit den Mädels (A night out with the girls. Don't use *Mädchen*, though, which is normally only used in reference to female children.)

Comment: Ich frage mich ob das tatsächlich wieder modern geworden ist. In meiner Jugend hat man niemanden mehr Mädel (erinnert auch an BDM) oder Bursche (Burschenschaftler?) genannt - schon gar nicht Bube. Vielleicht in Bayern, auf dem Land. Kann aber sein, dass es heute eine Renaissance erlebt. Ich würde zu Mädchen und Jungen für Kinder/Jugendliche bis 15/16 greifen, als respektvolle Form der Anrede. Ab da (junge) Frauen und Männer.

Comment: Bube ist vielleicht unüblich (außer vielleicht als Spitzbube), _Bub_ in Österreich völlig gängig (_Junge_ wird hierzulande idR als Teutonismus ermpfunden) und man kann auch das Wort _Bursche_ verwenden (zB im Sport, aber nicht nur) ohne Assoziationen zu nationalen und ähnlichen Studenten zu wecken.

Comment: Fehlt noch "Knabe".

Comment: Wird, außer im Weihnachtslied ("Sah ein Knab' ein Röslein steh'n") und vielleicht der Wendung "alter Knabe", hierzulande ebenfalls als eher "bundesdeutsch" empfunden. Wir nennen männlicher Kinder in diesem Alter idR "Buben".

Comment: Wer ist "wir"? Du und Deine Frau?

Comment: _Wir_ Österreicher. Hätte sich mE aus dem Kontext ergeben sollen, aber man darf sein Publikum nicht überschätzen.

Comment: Ich habe einen guten Freund, der auch Österreicher ist, und der vor Kasten, Paradeiser, Pickerl, Traffik usw. nicht zurückgeschreckt ist, als er noch bei uns Piefkes weilte, und den ich in mehr als einem Jahrzehnt nicht einmal "Bube" zu sagen gehört zu haben mich erinnere.

Comment: Nicht Bube sondern Bub (Mz.: Buben) statt Junge. Sogar der Duden kennt es: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bub

Comment: Ob Bub oder Bube - das eine ist eben die Kurzform wie Knab oder Bursch. Dass es der Duden kennt, dafür muss ich nicht nachschauen. Zu meiner Zeit war es veraltet - nur Greise sprachen von Jungen als Buben - das kann sich aber geändert haben. Nachdem zwischenzeitlich junge Erwachsene sich auch als Boys und Gilz bezeichnet haben fand man es vielleicht schick solche Begriffe zu reanimieren. Mag auch eine regionale Besonderheit sein.

Comment: Kurzform oder nicht, verwendet wird nur die eine Form, dh ohne -e. Und heute ist es eben nicht veraltet sondern süddt. Ansonsten hat sich der Sprachgebrauch diesbezüglich hierzulande nicht verändert. Womit nun aus meiner Sicht endgültig alles in diesem Zusammenhang gesagt ist. EOD.

Comment: Nur in der Antwort ist es nicht gesagt, da ist von "weit verbreitet" die Rede. (Übrigens: solche 'endgültig alles'/EOD - Versprechen hat noch selten jemand einhalten können; ich rate zur Sparsamkeit damit). :)

Answer (score 3):

*Mädels* bzw. *Jungs* hat eher einen umgangssprachlichen oder vertrauten Kontext. Wenn es um Kinder geht, darf man die Begriffe immer benutzen, aber sobald die besagten Personen aus dem Kindesalter sind, sollte man lieber darüber nachdenken.

Hier an der Uni habe ich aber erfahren, dass diese Begriffe unter den Studenten etwas mehr genutzt werden, z. B. *"die Mädels, die da rumhängen"* auch wenn man sie selber nicht so gut kennt und sie eigentlich in dem Alter sind, wo man sie als junge Frauen bezeichnen würde. Aber unter jungen Leuten ist Informalität allgemein eher angesagt und informelle Begriffe sind geläufiger als formelle.

Sobald es aber um die Arbeitswelt geht (oder man mit den Professoren redet), sollte immer professionell *Männer und Frauen* benutzt werden. Wenn man sich nicht sicher ist, in welchem Alter die Person ist (Kinder oder junge Teenager sind hier ausgeschlossen), oder nicht mit der Person vertraut ist, sollte man sicherheitshalber *(junge) Männer und Frauen* sagen.